# I need to change the chainset on my carrera vengance 27.5 frame and wheels

Tags: chain

What chainset would you recommend for my bike I'm new to cycling and pretty well I'm a virgin tbh,,,it's 24 speed carrera vengeance the one I have now well it looks like it's warped when peddling,It also slips whenever I put real pressure on it I smashed my knee last time on it...it also makes the chain hit the gear selector for the big cogs.thanks...

Comment: You should have some knowledgeable person look at it.  It could be a loose chainring or a loose bearing.  Even if the chainring is bent, it's often possible to straighten it with the application of a "monkey" wrench.

Comment: When you say "gear selector" is it the front or rear derailleur mechanism?

Comment: When you say "chainset" do you mean the entire chain transmission, or the front chainring?   Sound sto me like you have bent/buckled your big chainring from an impact, and the chain isn't running on it smoothly.  Please edit a clear and well lit photo into your question to help with identifying the issues.

Comment: It's the front 3 cogs the centre cog seems to be buckled I don't know how I haven't come off or no impact to it

Answer (score 1):

Have someone look at the crank. As mentioned in comments the whole crank may not need to be replaced.

If the crank does not replacement: The [Halfords web page for the current Vengance model](https://www.halfords.com/cycling/bikes/mountain-bikes/carrera-vengeance-mens-mountain-bike-black-16-18-20-22-frames) shows the bike has a mix of Shimano Altus and Tourney components, a Suntour XCE crank and a square taper cartridge bottom bracket.

Assuming your bike is the same, you can actually replace the crank with any square taper, triple ring crank designed for 8 rear gears, with the same chainring sizes (42/34/24 for the current model, but check what you have).

There are a number of manufacturers that make inexpensive cranks, a replacement Suntour or Shimano Altus crank are safe bets.

The Suntour XCE crank appears to have removable chainrings so if your big ring is damaged you will be able to replace it. Many inexpensive cranks are riveted together and the chainrings are not removable.

Comment: OK many thanks exactly the info I was after.